# Line Break between text + button isn't working in h1

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the button underneath the text (which currently says "test?") but the line break(s) is doing nothing. I've googled everything I can think of and can't find anything about this so any help is appreciated!

Html and the CSS for the button if that's relevant:

```css
.custom-button,
.custom-button:visited {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.custom-button:hover {
      background: #000;
      color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   Test? <br>
   <a class="custom-button" href="#scroll">Click Me</a>
</h1>
```

[image: And a picture to show what's currently happening]

EDIT: Here's the code for the header as well, it seems like the display: flex part is causing the problem but how do I centre the text vertically without that? This is all new to me, so thank you guy for the help!

```
h1 {
    font-size: 62px;
    font-family: "Sofia", sans-serif;
    color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: grey;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -10px;
    height: 110%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: Looks like the `h1` element has `display: flex` or some other setting which causes this. You should post the complete relevant code (both HTML and CSS, also parent element/s)

Comment: do you really need `display:flex` on the `h1` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the combination of `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`. Flexboxes are typically used to center things, so if you don't want it centered, there is little reason to use one.

Simply remove `display: flex` if you want it to set underneath the text. You can also remove `justify-content` and `align-items` when you do, as neither of those will affect anything if you remove `display: flex`:

```css
.custom-button,
.custom-button:visited {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.custom-button:hover {
      background: #000;
      color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   Test? <br>
   <a class="custom-button" href="#scroll">Click Me</a>
</h1>
```

Alternatively, if you want them both centered, you will need to apply your flex rules to *both* elements, *along with* `flex-direction: column` to ensure that the flexbox is vertical as opposed to horizontal:

```css
.custom-button,
.custom-button:visited {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.custom-button:hover {
      background: #000;
      color: #FFF;
}

h1, a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   Test? <br>
   <a class="custom-button" href="#scroll">Click Me</a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for the line break,
you need just to wrap the text into < p > tag

```
<h1>
   <p>Test?</p>
   <a class="custom-button" href="#scroll">Click Me</a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular *div* instead of *h1*, like this:

```
<div>
   <div>Test?</div>
   <div><a class="custom-button" href="#scroll">Click Me</a></div>
</div>
```

So, divs will behave as line breaks by default (i.e. display: block).
Also, you might want to add some additional styling, as well.

Comment: I'm using an h1 element because I have some cosmetic things that I want this part to have without it affecting the rest of the webpage (or at least, will has cosmetic things as it's currently in an extremely rough state w/ many place holders)

Comment: As for me, all cosmetic things can be done with a custom css class (using font-weight, padding, margin, color, etc). And I still think divs are a better option than <br> inside a <h1>. If you don't want to use divs, you can try <section> or something else with divs inside. Divs have a benefit: when you do the adaptive layout, it's easier to manipulate them than <br>